# Export data from matlab to csv

Tags: matlab

I am trying to use matlab's csvwrite to write an array to a csv file. However, matlab writes the data in the format like 2.008e+09. I don't want it to write in the e+09 form but the whole number expanded. How can I do it?

Answer (score 5):

`csvwrite` writes a maximum of 5 significant digits.

Use [`dlmwrite`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/dlmwrite.html) instead :

```
dlmwrite('test.csv',your_data, 'precision', 9) ; % 9 significant figures.
```